# Correlação entre duas curvas dose-resposta R?

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como fazer a correlação entre duas curvas de dose resposta do pacote "drc"?

Exemplo:

```
ryegrass.m1 <- drm(rootl~conc, data = ryegrass, fct = LL.4())
ryegrass.m2 <- drm(rootl~conc, data = ryegrass, fct = LL.3())
cor (ryegrass.m1, ryegrass.m2) #Não funciona
```

Meu objetivo é saber se as curvas são estatisticamente iguais ou diferentes.
E para plotar esse correlação deixar algo mais visual, está certo plotar assim?
Nesse exemplo a curva do modelo 2 fica praticamente toda dentro do intervalo de confiança da outra curva, isso quer dizer que elas são estatisticamente iguais?

```
plot(ryegrass.m1, broken = TRUE)
plot(ryegrass.m2, broken = TRUE, add = TRUE, type = "none", col = 2, lty = 2)  
plot(ryegrass.m1, broken = TRUE, type="confidence", add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se é o seguinte que quer, mas *"a correlação entre duas curvas"* pode ser dada com o seguinte código.
Primeiro obtemos os pontos das curvas com `predict` (na verdade o método para objetos de class `drc`, `predict.drc`.) Depois calculamos a correlação.

```
pred.m1 <- predict(ryegrass.m1)
pred.m2 <- predict(ryegrass.m2)
cor(pred.m1, pred.m2)
#[1] 0.9986341
```

Se o *"objetivo é saber se as curvas são estatisticamente iguais ou diferentes"* pode-se ainda fazer um [teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_Kolmogorov-Smirnov).

```
ks.test(pred.m1, pred.m2)
#        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#
#data:  pred.m1 and pred.m2
#D = 0.25, p-value = 0.4413
#alternative hypothesis: two-sided
#
#Warning message:
#In ks.test(pred.m1, pred.m2, exact = FALSE) :
#  p-value will be approximate in the presence of ties
```

Com um `p-value` igual a `0.44` a hipótese nula não é rejeitada.